# Coupled Limits and Convergence of Integrals

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits

Suppose a function f:[1,$\infty)\rightarrow(0,\infty)$ is monotone decreasing and suppose
 $\lim_{x\to\infty}\space x*f(x) = 0$. Is it true that $\int_{1}^{\infty}f(x)dx$ is convergent?

I was able to derive the following inequality for the integral using the monotone decreasing and positive properties,
$$x*f(x)\ge\int_{x}^{2x} f(u)du\ge0$$
$$0=\lim_{x\to\infty}\space x*f(x)\ge\lim_{x\to\infty}\space \int_{x}^{2x} f(u)du\ge0$$
therefore the limit of the integral must be $0$ and the integral can be split to yield,
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} (\int_{c}^{2x} f(u)du - \int_{c}^{x} f(u)du )= 0$$
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \int_{c}^{2x} f(u)du= \lim_{x\to\infty} \int_{c}^{x} f(u)du \quad .$$

Since the limits are both in x, I presume they cannot simply be assumed equal which would imply convergence. How can I finish this proof or disproof?

Comment: Try integrating $f(x) = \frac{1}{x*ln(1+x)}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the statement fails to hold. Consider
$$
\int_1^{+\infty} \frac {\mathrm dx} {x \log x},
$$
then $\lim_{x \to +\infty} x f(x) = 0$ and $f \searrow$ on $[1, +\infty)$, but the integral is just 
$$
\lim_{A\to +\infty} \int_1^A \frac {\mathrm dx} { x\log x} = \lim_{A \to +\infty} \log (\log A) = +\infty. 
$$

Comment: Thank-you for the counter-example. For the sake of learning more, is there a way to go about disproving this using the result that I derived, potentially using contradiction and the Cauchy-criteria for integrals?

Comment: @EthanBaltz Generally we prove things by reasoning, we disprove things by constructing counterexamples. But you could first do deduction, then construct examples to refute the result you have got.

Comment: If I might clarify, I guess my question is this. Does the final equality I proposed in some way restrict the function f into a simple contradiction? For instance, would using the fundamental theorem of calculus to get $$\lim_{x\to\infty} (F(2x) - F(x)) = 0$$ require the function to be 0 which it cannot be, thus being a counterexample?

Comment: Not necessarily. Suppose you are working with an integrable function. Then $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} (F(2x) - F(x)) \leq \lim_{x \rightarrow\infty} \int_{x}^{\infty} f(x)\,dx = 0$ by continuity of the integral. So the statement is true if $f$ is integrable and also true if it is not.

Comment: @EthanBaltz I don't think so. Even my example does not contradict this: here $F(x) =\log (\log x) $, and $$F(2x) - F(x) = \log \left(\frac {\log (2x)}{\log x}\right) = \log \left(\frac {\log 2}{\log x} + 1\right) \to \log 1 = 0 [x \to +\infty], $$ so the contradicting point is not this one.